# Why do these two arrays have the same shape?

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

So I am trying to create an array and then access the columns by name. So I came up with something like this:

```
import numpy as np
data = np.ndarray(shape=(3,1000),
                  dtype=[('x',np.float64),
                  ('y',np.float64),
                  ('z',np.float64)])
```

I am confused as to why

```
data.shape
```

and
`data['x'].shape`

both come back as (3,1000), this is causing me issues when I'm trying to populate my data fields

```
data['x'] = xvalues
```

where xvalues has a shape of (1000,).  Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: You are confusing the 'columns' defined by the `dtype` with the columns of a regular 2d array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why it comes out the same is because 'data' has a bit more structure than the one revealed by shape.

Example:

`data[0][0] returns`:
 (6.9182540632428e-310, 6.9182540633353e-310, 6.9182540633851e-310)

while `data['x'][0][0]:`
returns 6.9182540632427993e-310

so data contains 3 rows and 1000 columns, and the element of that is a 3-tuple.

data['x'] is the first element of that tuple of all combinations of 3 rows and 1000 columns, so the shape is (3,1000) as well.

Answer (score 0):

Just set `shape=(1000,)`.  The triple dtype will create 3 columns.